# Ocaml printing one statement after another

Tags: ocaml

I am very new to Ocaml and ML in general and I have been having a very fundamental issue. I am using a pattern match and within one match I would like to print two or more concatenated statements. Eg.
`chan^"("^var^")"^op2^(poc p); chan^"("^var^")"^op^(poc p)`

```
let processoperatorchange2 t2s2 proc2 op op2=
  let rec poc2 p = match p with
    | Zero ->  "0"
    | Pproc (x) -> String.lowercase x
    | In(chan, var, _, p, _) ->  chan^"("^var^")"^op^(poc2 p); chan^"("^var^")"^op2^(poc2 p)
  in poc2 proc2
```

But then each time I run this, the only statement printed is the last one after the semi colon. Can I get some help with this?

Comment: Could you add the whole match expression ? From your question I can guess that you return a string instead of printing it.

Comment: Hi, yes I have just edited the question with the code. The issue is that the concatenated string is a combination of different user defined types so for now I simply print it but whenever I assign to a variable, it returns unit and I am unable to print it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does not print a statement but builds a string, thus it returns a value, and doesn't perform any side-effects. The semicolon operator, when interspersed between two expressions, doesn't combine the value produced from these expressions, thus if you have `"hello"; "world"` the result is `"world"`. That is what happens in your case when you do

```
chan^"("^var^")"^op^(poc2 p); chan^"("^var^")"^op2^(poc2 p)
```

Everything on the lift is just thrown away.

A quick fix would be to concatenate them, e.g.,

```
chan^"("^var^")"^op^(poc2 p) ^ ";\n" ^ chan^"("^var^")"^op2^(poc2 p)
```

But in general, an idiomatic way to print AST is to use the `Format` module, and implement a recursive `pp` function, that has type `Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit`. Note the return type, the function doesn't build a string (that is usually an operation of quadratic complexity), but rather prints it into generic output stream.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the pointer. I will try the Format.Formatter option. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I have a follow up question. Assuming I wanted to build this string in my question in order to add it to a Set, what is the best approach? At the moment I am printing it out but what if I wanted to actually to assign it to a string variable? Each time I do it that way it returns unit

Comment: You can use Format.asprintf function to print into string.